# Multiple Page Meeting Work Space - Pages Tabs Missing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, meeting-workspace

After upgrading to SharePoint 2010, the ability view pages within a multi-page work space has been broken. If I navigate to Manage Pages within the Site Actions menu, I can see the pages, and if I add a new page, all of the pages will be visible until the next page refresh.

I have verified the correct masterpage mwsdefaultv4) is the default master page. If I try to activate the publishing infrastructure, I get an activation error that the Pages Lists already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I see a potential confusion being made here - Meeting Workspaces are not (by default) relying on Publishing infrastructure. Besides this, considering the upgrade variable - in SharePoint 2010 the pages are stored in the Site Pages library.

If you already have the Pages library it will never work, and you should probably delete that library, also because Publishing page also rely on Page Layouts and associated Content Types.

I would suggest NOT to use Publishing features on Meeting workspaces, because they have specific functionality, not meant for a Publishing site.

Comment: That makes sense, any ideas on getting the page links to display?

Comment: If you are referring to the links that usual appear on Meeting Workspaces with Pages, that would only work with Site Pages library